# ionice vs. Software-RAID

Tags: linux, raid, scheduling, ionice

Does ionice work in Software-RAID environments?
I cannot set the CFQ scheduler for the md devices, because there is no file /sys/block/md0/queue/scheduler .
It seems that the scheduler settings for the underlying disks are not propagated to the raid devices.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Chris Siebenmann recently came to the same conclusion as you:  ionice has no effect on either "software raid" (I presume this means MD) or LVM.

http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/